# How to convert type from "str" to "numpy.string_" of each ndarray items?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Env: Python 3.6, Numpy 1.14.0

`a = {ndarray}['中','中']`

I need to convert `str` type to `numpy.string_`.

A single `str` can be converted like this: `np.string_('中', encoding='utf-8')]`

But, how to convert a ndarray with a single statement not loop?

`a.astype(np.string_)` will raise a error:

> {SystemError} returned a result with an error set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.char` has functions that apply `str` methods to elements of an array:

```
In [367]: a = np.array(['中','中'])
In [368]: np.string_(a[0], encoding='utf-8')
Out[368]: b'\xe4\xb8\xad'
In [369]: np.char.encode(a, encoding='utf-8')
Out[369]: array([b'\xe4\xb8\xad', b'\xe4\xb8\xad'], dtype='|S3')
```

`np.string_` is a bytestring, while `np.str` is unicode (in py3).  So this translates a 'U1' array into a 'S3' array.

```
In [370]: a
Out[370]: array(['中', '中'], dtype='<U1')
```