# Python h5py - Why do I get a broadcast error?

Tags: python, numpy, unicode, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to read a .h5 file `data.h5`, which has 2 datasets, 'Data' and 'metaData'. 'metaData' contains a dictionary which is 157x1, and looks like this:

[image]

Then, I am trying to write a new .h5 file, which contains 3 columns: the number, name (1st column of dictionary), and unit (last column of dictionary) of each variable in the dictionary. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py as h5

hdf = h5.File('data.h5','r')
data1 = hdf.get('Data')
data2 = hdf.get('metaData')
dataset1 = np.array(data1)
dataset2 = np.array(data2)

#dictionary
hdfdic = dict(hdf['metaData'])
dic = hdfdic.get('dictionary')
dictionary = np.array(dic)

#write new h5 file
with h5.File('telemetry.h5', 'w') as var:

    dt = np.dtype( [('n°', int), ('Variable name', 'S10'), ('Unit', 'S10')] )
    dset = var.create_dataset( 'data', dtype=dt, shape = (len(dictionary),))

    dset['n°'] = np.arange(len(dictionary))
    dset['Variable name'] = [val[1] for val in dictionary[:][0][0]]
    dset['Unit'] = [val[2] for val in dictionary[:][0][-1]]

    data = dset[:]
    print(data)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/new/code.py", line 28, in <module>
    dset['Variable name'] = [val[1] for val in dictionary[:][0][0]]
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py", line 707, in __setitem__
    for fspace in selection.broadcast(mshape):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\selections.py", line 299, in broadcast
    raise TypeError("Can't broadcast %s -> %s" % (target_shape, self.mshape))
TypeError: Can't broadcast (4,) -> (157,)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: `dictionary` is a numpy array.  Indexing it with `[:]` does nothing.  You may want to use `dictionary[:,0,0]`.  But that's just a guess because I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj noted, h5py returns HDF5 datasets as NumPy arrays. It can be confusing at first -- h5py uses Python's dictionary syntax to reference HDF5 objects (groups and datasets), but they are not dictionaries! Your attempt is on the right track. You need to modify it to work with data from `hdf['metaData']` as a NumPy array instead of list.

Example below should work. Since I don't have the starting file (`data.h5`), I created a file to replicate the values in the image. Code to create that file is at the end.

Note 1: This example would be simpler if it didn't use use `'°'` for degree. That adds a extra step working with string data. That's why I used `np.char.decode()` to print `dset['Variable name']` and `dset['Unit']`. More about that below.

Note 2: Be careful using hard-code string sizes. `('Variable name', 'S10')` is from the answer to an earlier question (that had shorter strings). The code below gets the size from the `hdf['metaData']` dataset dtype, then uses it when defining the dtype used for the new dataset in `telemetry.h5`.

```
with h5.File('data.h5','r') as hdf:
     #read dataset as a numpy array metaData, it is not a dictionary
     metaData = hdf['metaData'][:]
     print('dtype is:',metaData.dtype)
     
#write new h5 file
with h5.File('telemetry.h5', 'w') as var:

    dt = np.dtype( [('n°', int), ('Variable name', metaData.dtype), ('Unit', metaData.dtype)] )
    dset = var.create_dataset( 'data', dtype=dt, shape=(len(metaData),))

    dset['n°'] = np.arange(metaData.shape[0])
    dset['Variable name'] = metaData[:,0] # use first column of metaData
    dset['Unit'] =  metaData[:,-1]  # use last column of metaData

    for row in dset:
        print(row[0], np.char.decode(row[1]), np.char.decode(row[2]))
```

Here is the code I wrote to mimic `data.h5`. When you printed the raw data (as byte strings), you see `b'\xc2\xb0'` where you expect `'°'` for degree units.  There are some complications with that character with h5py. It is fine in Python and NumPy. However, h5py (and HDF5) don't support NumPy's Unicode dtype; you need to use Numpy byte arrays ('S' dtype). That's why I used `np.char.encode()` to encode array `arr` to `arr2` before saving with h5py. That's why `np.char.decode()` is necessary when printing `dset['Variable name']` and `dset['Unit']` above -- you have to decode the encoded string byte data back to Unicode.

```
arr = np.array( \
    [['ADC_ALT_TC', 'ADC_ALT_TC',  'ADC.ALT:TC [ft]', 'ft'],
      ['ADC_AOA_TC', 'ADC_AOA_TC',  'ADC.AOA:TC [°]', '°'],
      ['ADC_AOS_TC', 'ADC_AOS_TC',  'ADC.AOS:TC [°]', '°'],
      ['ADC_CAS_TC', 'ADC_CAS_TC',  'ADC.CAS:TC [kts]', 'kts'],
      ['ADC_OAT_TC', 'ADC_OAT_TC',  'ADC.OAT:TC [°]'., '°'],
      ['ADC_SpeedWarning_TC', 'ADC_SpeedWarning_TC','ADC_SpeedWarning:TC', ''],
      ['ADC_Stall_TC', 'ADC_Stall_TC','ADC_Stall:TC', ''],
      ['ADC_TAS_TC', 'ADC_TAS_TC',  'ADC.TAS:TC [kts]', 'kts'],
      ['AHRS1_accX_TC', 'AHRS1_accX_TC',  'AHRS1.accX:TC [m/s^2]', 'm/s^2'],
      ['AHRS1_accY_TC', 'AHRS1_accY_TC',  'AHRS1.accX:TC [m/s^2]', 'm/s^2'],
      ['AHRS1_accZ_TC', 'AHRS1_accZ_TC',  'AHRS1.accX:TC [m/s^2]', 'm/s^2'] ]
print(arr)
arr2 = np.char.encode(arr)
print(arr2)

with h5.File('data.h5','w') as hdf:
     hdf.create_dataset('metaData',data=arr2)
```

Here are some references for those that need more details about the underlying HDF5/h5py requirement, or encoding/decoding between Unicode and string bytes:

- [Strings in HDF5 - Encodings](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html#encodings)
- [Conversion from U3 dtype to ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38641632/10462884)
- [How to convert type from “str” to “numpy.string_” of each ndarray items?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48435356/10462884)