# Datetime storing in hd5 database

Tags: python, datetime, h5py

I have a list of np.datetime64 data that looks as follows:

```
times =[2015-03-26T16:02:42.000000Z,
 2015-03-26T16:02:45.000000Z,...]

type(times) returns list

type(times[1]) returns obspy.core.utcdatetime.UTCDateTime
```

Now, I understand that h5py does not support date time data.

I have tried the following:

```
time_str = [n.encode("ascii", "ignore") for n in time_str]
time_str = [str(s) for s in time_str]

type(time_str[1]) returns bytes
```

I am okay with creating the dataset and storing these date time values as a string

However, when attempting to create the dataset, I get the following error:

```
with h5py.File('data_ML.hdf5', 'w') as f:
           f.create_dataset("time", data=time_str,maxshape=(None),chunks=True, dtype='str')

TypeError: No conversion path for dtype: dtype('<U')
```

Where am I messing up/ is there an alternative way to store these values as is so I can extract them later?

Comment: What does `type(time_str[1])` give you?

Comment: it gives me: bytes

Comment: I think you need to make it String, not Bytes, as your dtype='str'

Comment: Would it be in the n.encode? I thought I was converting them to strings already

Comment: h5py doesn't support NumPy's Unicode dtype. You have to use string dtype. So, if you have `U20`, use `S20` instead. Read this: [h5py: What about NumPy’s U type?](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/strings.html#what-about-numpy-s-u-type). SO has several questions and answers on this subject. This is a recent one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68199414/10462884 -- note: it needs a better title, it's not really a broadcast error.

Comment: Yes, I read about the numpy unicode. I am just very confused since I never dealt with h5py and conversions like this are very unclear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here we go. I couldn't get some of you code to work together (maybe you left some steps out, or changed variable names?). And, I could not get the `obspy.core.utcdatetime.UTCDateTime` object your have.

So I created an example that does the following:

1. Starts with a list of `np.datetime64()` objects,
2. Converts to a list of `np.datetime_as_string()` in UTC format
   objects **see note at Item 4
3. Converts to a `np.array` with `dtype='S30'`
4. Note: I included Step 2 to replicate your data. See following section
   for simpler version

**Code below:**

```
times =[np.datetime64('2015-03-26T16:02:42.000000'),
        np.datetime64('2015-03-26T16:02:45.000000'),
        np.datetime64('2015-03-26T16:02:48.000000'),
        np.datetime64('2015-03-26T16:02:55.000000') ]

utc_times = [ np.datetime_as_string(n,timezone='UTC') for n in times ]
  
utc_str_arr = np.array(utc_times,dtype='S30')   

with h5py.File('data_ML.hdf5', 'w') as f:
     f.create_dataset("time", data=utc_str_arr,maxshape=(None),chunks=True)
```

You can simplify the process if you are starting with `np.datetime64()` objects, and don't have (and don't need or want) the intermediate list of string objects (variable `utc_times` in my code). The method below skips Step 2 above, and shows 2 ways to create a `np.array()` of properly encoded strings.

**Code below:**

```
times =[np.datetime64('2015-03-26T16:02:42.000000'),
        np.datetime64('2015-03-26T16:02:45.000000'),
        np.datetime64('2015-03-26T16:02:48.000000'),
        np.datetime64('2015-03-26T16:02:55.000000') ]

# Create empty array with defined size and 'S#' dtype, then populate with for loop:
utc_str_arr1 = np.empty((len(times),),dtype='S30')
for i, n in enumerate(times):
    utc_str_arr1[i] = np.datetime_as_string(n,timezone='UTC')

# -OR- Create array and populate using loop comprehension:
utc_str_arr2 = np.array( [np.datetime_as_string(n,timezone='UTC').encode('utf-8') for n in times] )

with h5py.File('data_ML.hdf5', 'w') as f:
     f.create_dataset("time1", data=utc_str_arr1,maxshape=(None),chunks=True)
     f.create_dataset("time2", data=utc_str_arr2,maxshape=(None),chunks=True)
```

Final result looks similar with either method (second method creates 2 identical datsets).
Image from **HDFView**:
[image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921593/10462884]

**To Read the Data:**
Per request in Aug-02-2021 comment, here is the code to extract data from HDF5 and create Pandas timestamp objects (then saved to a dataframe). First the byte strings in the dataset are read and converted to NumPy Unicode strings with `.astype()`. Then the strings are converted to Pandas timestamp objects with `pd.to_datetime()` using the `format=` parameter.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with h5py.File('data_ML.hdf5', 'r') as h5f:
    ## returns a h5py dataset object:
    dts_ds = h5f["time"]
    longest_word=len(max(dts_ds, key=len))
    
    ## returns an array of byte strings representing np.datetime64:
    ## .astype() used to convert byte strings to unicode
    dts_arr = dts_ds[:].astype('U'+str(longest_word))

    ## create a new array to hold Pandas datetime objects
    ## then loop over first array to convert and populate new array
    pd_dts_arr = np.empty((dts_arr.shape[0],),dtype=object)
    for i, dts in enumerate(dts_arr):    
        pd_dts_arr[i] = pd.to_datetime(dts, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        
    dts_df = pd.DataFrame(pd_dts_arr)
```

There are a lot of ways to represent dates and time using native Python, NumPy and Pandas objects. More details about working with them can be found at this answer:
[Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921593/10462884)

Comment: THANK YOU! This solved the issue beautifully

Comment: PS... For opening the hdf file and then comparing it back to a pandas timestamp, what would the approach be?

Comment: @Steve Bermeo...that's a different (new) question. :-) Your example starts with a list of `np.datetime64` data. I am not familiar with Pandas timestamp objects. Do they use `np.datetime64` to save time/date data? If so, you simply reserve the steps above -- 1) open the file in read mode, 2) read the `time` dataset (as an array of strings), 3) then convert the strings back to `np.datetime64` objects.

Comment: Hi Steve. Challenge accepted. I added to my previous answer showing how to read the data and convert to a Pandas timestamp object (at least, I think that's the object you want). Check out the linked answer at the end. It covers just about every date/time object conversion you might want to do. The trick in my code is reading the HDF5 byte strings and coverting to a format you can use with one of those methods.